# ora-01858 error with to_date in regexp_replace

Tags: oracle11g

I have several rows in my table like below:

```
row1:  abc    changed on   12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1  
row2:  defg   updated      14 January, 2012 08:20 PM         ......region2  
row3:  ghijkl corrected by 18 august, 2013 9:30 AM    ..something..region3
```

My requirement is as follows:

1. All the above dates are in EST time zone and date format is exactly as above and does not change.
2. I want to update the dates in these rows from EST to different time zones as per the region in that row, and the format should be changed to something like `12 dec 2016 7:30 AM`.

So the query I framed is (taking row1 as example) as below:

```
select regexp_replace(
     'abc changed on 12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1',
     '([0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])      (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(,[[:blank:]])([0-9]{4})([[:blank:]])([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])(AM|PM)','\1-\3-\5 \7 \9',1,0,'i')
```

output:

```
abc changed on 12-November-2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1
```

So I am happy with the above query till now because I get a string
with the formatted date. Even though this is not the final date
format, I can use this date to pass to some function which  converts
this date according to the region do some processing and fianlly
return a date type.For the same purpose I add to_date in the above
query:

```
 select regexp_replace(
   'abc changed on 12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1',
   '([0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])   (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(,[[:blank:]])([0-9]{4})([[:blank:]])([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])(AM|PM)',
 substr('\1-\3-\5 \7 \9',1),
 1,0,'i')
```

output:

```
abc changed on 12-November-2008 11:30 AM and its
abc..region1 --> works fine till here
```

Now I am adding to_date to convert the date string type to real date
type to do some processing on it:

```
select regexp_replace(
   'abc changed on 12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1',
   '([0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])   (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(,[[:blank:]])([0-9]{4})([[:blank:]])([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])(AM|PM)',
 to_date(substr('\1-\3-\5 \7 \9',1),'dd-mon-yyyy HH:MI AM'),
 1,0,'i')
```

This query is giving me an error:

```
 ORA-01858: a non-numeric character found where a numeric was expected
```

I checked whether wrong parameters were being passed to
 `to_date()`, and fired the query below, but it worked fine.

```
 Select to_date('12-November-2008 11:30 AM','dd-mon-yyyy HH:MI AM') 
   from dual;
```

output:

```
12-Nov-2008
```

(I am not worried with the timestamp because itnternall it will be anyways in this date)

To avoid confusion I have numbered the substrings of the regular expression above:

```
([0-9]{2})-->1 ([[:blank:]])-->2
(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)-->3
```

(,[[:blank:]])-->4 ([0-9]{4})-->5 ([[:blank:]])-->6
 ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})-->7 ([[:blank:]])-->8 (AM|PM)-->9

```
select regexp_replace(
 'abc changed on 12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1',
 '([0-9]{2})([[:blank:]])          (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(,[[:blank:]])([0-9]{4})([[:blank:]])([0-9]{2}:[0-9]
{2})([[:blank:]])(AM|PM)','\1-\3-\5 \7 \9',1,0,'i')
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. It would be helpful; to show the exact output you are expecting. Are you just trying to change the format of the date in your original string? Will it be a fixed date, or could it be any date in that format?

Comment: Not that it changes anything for you, but is the lack of a space in the regex parameter intentional: `November,2008`?, the source string has a space, so will not match the search string.

Comment: Hi..I have added complete details now..Please check and help..Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string always has the date in it in that particular format (and that there are no invalid dates etc etc) then the following should work for you:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT ' the date is 12 November, 2008 11:30 AM' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'Here''s a date of 1 March, 2015 1:43 pm' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '1 February,2016 9:43 AM' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'And again it''s 21 May, 2016 9:43 AM and a little bit extra' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       to_date(regexp_replace(str, '^.*?([[:digit:]]{1,2} [[:alpha:]]{3,9}, ?[[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{1,2}\:[[:digit:]]{2} (A|P)M).*$', '\1', 1, 1, 'i'), 'dd Month yyyy, hh:mi am') dt
FROM   sample_data;

 STR                                                        DT
---------------------------------------------------------- -------------------
 the date is 12 November, 2008 11:30 AM                    12/11/2008 11:30:00
Here's a date of 1 March, 2015 1:43 pm                     01/03/2015 13:43:00
1 February,2016 9:43 AM                                    01/02/2016 09:43:00
And again it's 21 May, 2016 9:43 AM and a little bit extra 21/05/2016 09:43:00
```

The regular expression can be broken down as follows:

1. `^.*?` - match any character (except new line) from the start of the line as few times as possible, which may be 0 or more.
2. `([[:digit:]]{1,2} [[:alpha:]]{3,9}, ?[[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{1,2}\:[[:digit:]]{2} (A|P)M)` - this is the pattern we're looking for, and which we'll use to replace the whole string with (this is aliased as `\1`, which we can then pass into the replace string parameter).
3. `.*$` - match any character up to the end of the string

The second part of the pattern can be further broken down as:

1. `[[:digit:]]{1,2}` - one or two digits
2. - a single space character
3. `[[:alpha:]]{3,9}` - three to nine letters (upper or lower case)
4. `, ?` -  a comma followed by 0 or 1 spaces
5. `[[:digit:]]{4}` - four digits
6. - a single space character
7. `[[:digit:]]{1,2}` - one or two digits
8. `\:` - a single colon character
9. `[[:digit:]]{1,2}` - two digits
10. - a single space character
11. `(A|P)M` - either the letter A or P followed by an M

---

This should do the trick for you:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 'abc    changed on   12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'defg   updated      14 January, 2012 08:20 PM         ......region2' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'ghijkl corrected by 18 august, 2013 9:30 AM    ..something..region3' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       regexp_replace(str,
                      '(^.*?)(([[:digit:]]{1,2}) (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December), (?[[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{1,2}\:[[:digit:]]{2} (A|P)M))(.*$)',
                      '\1\3-\4-\5\7', 1, 1, 'i') dt
FROM   sample_data;

STR                                                                 DT
------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc    changed on   12 November, 2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1 abc    changed on   12-November-2008 11:30 AM and its abc..region1
defg   updated      14 January, 2012 08:20 PM         ......region2 defg   updated      14-January-2012 08:20 PM         ......region2
ghijkl corrected by 18 august, 2013 9:30 AM    ..something..region3 ghijkl corrected by 18-august-2013 9:30 AM    ..something..region3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concern Boneist.I have added a lot of details to my question.Please check and help.